# SQL column showing -1 if column is nothing inserted

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

In my SQL Server table, if the column value(integer) is nothing it's inserting value is -1. If i select all column values from table and showing on ASP.net grid it is showing -1 on specified column. I don't want to show it as -1 it need show like some thing like "null or none". How can get this?

Comment: Does the column have a default value of -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 You can insert null in your DataBase. (In your datas you use Type Nullable in order to match )

2 You can also treat your information in your Gridview, by deleting -1 and replacing with null value.

```
 void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {

    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

      e.Row.Cells[1].Text = (e.Row.Cells[1].Text == "-1" ) ? "" :  e.Row.Cells[1].Text;

    }

  }
```

Comment: Yes.. exactly i want to like this.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

make that column null-able and don't set default value for that column and in asp.net page check if there are null then replace that to bank or "none"

Answer (score 0):

So either in your update statement, or in the driver you're using, '' and nothing are likely being mishandled.  Ff you want NULL, you have to insert NULL.

- Insert into (mytable ID, SomeNum, SomeText) Values (1,'','hello
  World') Nope
- Insert into (mytable ID, SomeNum, SomeText) Values
  (1,,'hello World') Nope
- Insert into (mytable ID, SomeNum, SomeText)
  Values (1,NULL,'hello World') Yep.

all result in different values in someNum.   the first may throw a type conversion, the 2nd I believe results in -1 and the 3rd will give you the result you're looking for.

If you're using a stored procedure, the parameter being passed in is not being handled appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling an event and avoid an unneccesary postback to server, write the following code after you get the DataTable from database and before you Databind() your GridView.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //DataTable dt = GetDataFromDatabase();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        row["columnName"] = row["columnName"]== "-1" ? "none" : row["columnName"];
    }
}
```